# Java how to return an array with fibonacci values starting at 1?

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors, fibonacci

I'm writing a void function `fibFill` which fills an array with Fibonacci numbers. It doesn't have to return anything.

Here's what I have so far:

```
void fibFill(int[] fibo) {
    fibo[0] = 1;
    fibo[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < fibo.length; i++) {
        fibo[i] = fibo[i - 1] + fibo[i - 2];
    }
    int pos(int position) {
        return fibo[pos];
    }
}
```

For example, if I pass an array of length 5 to the method, it will override the contents of the passed array like this: `[1, 1, 2, 3, 5]`

Comment: I don't see any problems with this code

Comment: this function will throw if `fibo` is too small.

Comment: Why not use an ArrayList?

Comment: @Maljam: Problem: This: `return fibo[pos]` does not jibe with this: `void`. If you want the method to *return* an array of int, then declare it to do so: `public int[] fibFill(int length)`

Comment: Plus this `an input of a length 5` does not jibe with: `fibFill(int[] fibo)`. Have the method accept a single int parameter not an int array. You would do well to read the tutorial on method parameters and return types.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Oh, I thought it was another method..

Comment: The `return fibo[pos]` corresponds to the `int` return type of the (mistakenly embedded) `pos()` method.

Comment: Presumably you are asking about the compilation errors, but it it isn't clear from what you've writtten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `fibFill` method shouldn't have a `pos` method embedded in it; and I would make it `static` (so it can be called without an instance), like

```
static void fibFill(int[] fibo) {
    fibo[0] = 1;
    fibo[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < fibo.length; i++) {
        fibo[i] = fibo[i - 1] + fibo[i - 2];
    }
}
```

Then you can test it with something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] fib = new int[10];
    fibFill(fib);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fib));
}
```

Which outputs (as requested) the fibonacci values starting at 1

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

Answer (score 1):

fixed:

```
static void fibFill(int [] fibo) {
if(fibo.length==0) return;
if(fibo.length==1)
    {
        fibo[0]=1;
        return;
    }
fibo[0] = 1;
fibo[1] = 1;
for (int i = 2;i < fibo.length; i++) 
    {
        fibo[i]=fibo[i-1]+fibo[i-2];
    }
}

//there is no need for pos, as you can get it by type fibo[index]
```

Note that this solution cost you O(n), you can also do it directly by formula and there is also more ways to calculate fibonacci. for more information:
[five ways to calculate fibonacci](http://sahandsaba.com/five-ways-to-calculate-fibonacci-numbers-with-python-code.html)

Comment: This method will fail for a 0-element array.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (n==0||n==1) {
    return n;
}
int smallassumption=fib(n-1);
int smallassumption2=fib(n-2);
int ans=smallassumption+smallassumption2;
return ans;
```